# What type of video player is this?

Tags: html5, video, flash

I'm looking for something like this video player (http://www.be-creative.tv/#/brian-Leonard-02-02/) or something very similar. Does anyone have any ideas? Doesn't necessarily have to be free. HTML 5 would be preferred as well. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged with "wordpress?"

Answer (score 1):

If you want *that* player, you can [get it at ActiveDen](http://activeden.net/item/clean-white-video-player/82263).

If you need something you can depend on, [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) is near-ubiquitous, heavily tested, and skinnable to look pretty much however you want if you put a little work into it. See my comment above about why this question is tagged with "wordpress," but if you do need integration, [there's a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/).

If you want free(and HTML5), consider [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

That's a flash video player. There are hundreds of them here: http://activeden.net/category/flash/video-players